# Java SOJO CSV Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, csv

I am trying to use SOJO to serialize a Java object to CSV. The example looks pretty straight forward:

```
Car car = new Car("My Car");
car.setDescription("This is my car.");
Serializer csvSerializer = new CsvSerializer();
String csvStr = (String) csvSerializer.serialize(car);
System.out.println(csvStr);
// print:
// description,build,properties,name,~unique-id~,class  
// This is my car.,,,My Car,0,test.net.sf.sojo.model.Car
```

I tried implementing my own version of the example. I made a really simple `Car` class with two `String` fields (`build` and `description`) which implements a `setDescription(..)` method.

This is what I implemented:

```
import net.sf.sojo.interchange.csv.CsvSerializer;


public class Main {

private class Car
{
    private String build;
    private String description;
    public Car(String build) {
        this.build = build;
        this.description = null;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    Car car = m.new Car("My Car");
    car.setDescription("This is my car.");
    CsvSerializer csvSerializer = new CsvSerializer();
    String csvStr = (String) csvSerializer.serialize(car);
    System.out.println(csvStr);
}

}
```

However, when I run my implementation I get the following output:

```
~unique-id~,class,description
0,Main$Car,
```

I don't understand why in my implementation neither the `build` or `description` fields are serialized, can you help?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used SOJO, but for private fields you probably need getter methods; or you could try declaring the fields public.

Answer (score 1):

From the SOJO home page: "The intention for this project is a Java framework, that convert JavaBeans in a simplified representation"

The Car object in your example does not qualify.  You must have a getter (and, probabaly, a setter as well) for every property that you wish SOJO to write to (or read from) your file.  Add getBuild() and getDescription()

Comment: Yes, It does to work without the setters, even public fields without setters dont prints out to CSV.